# Avoiding the Reflection overhead

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.reflection

I have a number of methods that can return a `string`, `bool`, `int` or a `tuple<int,bool>` or if the method fails, returns a class with a numnber of properties in it detailing the in and out params.

Is there a way that when the call returns that I can avoid using Reflection to determine the return types and the values? The code is for low end mobile devices using Xamarin (so both iOS and Android)

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're doing, and you haven't posted any code to demonstrate.  Are you saying your methods return `System.Object` and you have to use type checking to determine result?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to traverse through the class properties without reflection.

But As a last resort, you can override the class `ToString()` method and manually return what you want to return. But you need to be careful as the every time you edit your class you need to update `ToString()`